# Linux C write buffer to file from a while loop issue

Tags: c, linux

I have the following function (that dumps a process memory region). If I write to stdout `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, rd);` it outputs the buffer correctly, the problem rises when I want to write the buffer to a file, the file gets written but with the same date over and over:

```
void dump_region(int fd, off64_t start, off64_t end)
{
        char buf[4096];
        int fdo;

        fdo = open("memdump_log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
        if (fdo == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "open failed: %m\n");
                close(fd);
                exit(1);
        }

        lseek64(fd, start, SEEK_SET);
        while(start < end) {
                int rd;

                rd = read(fd, buf, 4096);
                write(fdo, buf, rd);
                //write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, rd);
                start += 4096;
        }
        close(fdo);
}
```

The function is accessed from `main()` like this:

```
if(maps && mem != -1) {
        char buf[BUFSIZ + 1];

        while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, maps)) {
                off64_t start, end;

                sscanf(buf, "%llx-%llx", &start, &end);
                dump_region(mem, start, end);
        }
}
```

Any idea where am I wrong?

Comment: Also, i think you should write `start += rd` instead of `start += 4096`.

Comment: Exactly the same output with `start += rd` or `start += 4096`

Comment: BTW, wouldn't make more sense to declare `char buf[BUFSIZ];` then `rd = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZ);` or better `rd = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify

```
    fdo = open("memdump_log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
```

into

```
    fdo = open("memdump_log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0644);
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I tried before with `fdo = open("memdump_log", O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0644);` but failed, forgot the `O_WRONLY`

Answer (score 2):

You need to seek to the end of your output file, or passing the `O_APPEND` to open

Answer (score 2):

You keep reopening the output file on every call to dump_region. When opening a file it will always start writing at the start. Either keep the file open all the time, seek to the end, or try the O_APPEND flag.